# How do I find the installation path of binutils, gcc-3.4.4.tar.gz in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, c

I have ubuntu 8.10. In this I could find the binutils, gcc are installed. But when ever I try to know that glibc, glibc-linuxthreads are installed are not.

It showing that no package is found.

For that I have downloaded glibc-2.3.3.tar.gz, glibc-linuxthreads-2.3.3.tar.gz.I want to install these two package.i dont know where to install as am novice to linux. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Installing from source is not necessary or friendly to new users so you should stick with the package management system. You can use `apt-get` at the command line or you can use the "Synaptic Package Manager" GUI.

[image: synaptic]

Note: Use `man apt-get` and read the manual for apt-get to learn how to use it.